# Failed: GAM Applications Registration

Tags: genexus

Estamos teniendo un problema con GAM.
Actualizamos una KB de genexus 17 U10 a Gx 17 U11 y cuando vamos hacer un rebuild al momento de registrar la aplicación en gam da error. Intentamos hacerlo mediante las funcionalidades del menú Genexus Accesss Manager en Tools en el IDE, primero inicializando la metadata y luego registrando la aplicación, pero sigue dando error.

El problema es que no nos da mucha información y no sabemos si hay algún log donde podremos ver más detalles del error y ver cual es la causa.

¿Alguna idea de que pueda ser?

Este es el error:

```
Success: Integrated Security Initialization
========== GAM Applications Registration started ==========
Registering 'InspeccioneVehicular'...Failed
Failed: GAM Applications Registration
```

Muchas gracias!

Saludos
Alvaro

Comment: SOLUCIONADO.
Lo solucioné ejecutando el script SQL del gam "ReorganizationScript405To406.txt" se ve que por algún motivo no se actualizó la base de datos y por ese motivo daba error al intentar registrar la aplicación.